# Checkbox not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Why is it that the jquery is returning checking box value as true when not checked.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UserMetadata.CheckBoxRememberMe)

---------------------------------------------------------
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnSignIn").click(function () {
        console.log($('#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.UserMetadata.CheckBoxRememberMe)').val())
});
```

Comment: Because that's how checkboxes work.   Look at the *rendered* output.

Comment: In summary, the checkbox name is only POST'd when it's checked and is POST'd with true.  If it's not ticked, it will not be in the form POST.   ASP.Net gets around this by adding a checkbox with value=true and then immediately after it a hidden input with the same name with value=false.  This way, the name is POST'd with either true or false, rather than true or not POST'd.